# How can I get Barbie Pet Rescue working on Windows 10?

Tags: barbie-pet-rescue

Does anyone know how to get Barbie Pet Rescue to work on Windows 10? I get sound, just the picture is off...

[image]

Comment: nvrm figured it out.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct so your post can help people who have the same issue in  the future

Comment: @keithM - RoElizabeth posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find compatibility mode, so I went to *This PC*, right-clicked the program and clicked "Create Shortcut". I was then able to right-click the new desktop icon, right-click *Properties* and find the *Compatibility* tab.

There is an option: *Run this program in compatibility mode for:*, which I picked *Windows 95*. I also picked:

- Reduce color mode: 16-bit (65536) Color
- Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution, and
- Run this program as Administrator

just to be safe. I'm not sure if the first two did anything, but this worked for me.

Comment: Good to hear you solved the problem! And thanks for writing an answer, this will help others if they have the same problem in future :)